# Creating the child record based on parent field

Tags: trigger, controller

Opportunity-->Pif(Child)
Opportunity-->Proposal(Child)
I have a logic for for single PIF can able to create many propsals.
Now Requirement is I have many PIF's and each PIF(PIF_GDS__c) have each proposal(Quote__c).
Proposal API--> Quote__C.

```
trigger ProposalMappingtoPIF on Quote__c (after insert) {

    Set<ID> sPIFIDs= New Set<ID>();
    Map<ID,PIF_GDS__c> mPIF= New  Map<ID,PIF_GDS__c>();
    List<PIF_GDS__c> lupdatePIF= New List<PIF_GDS__c>();

    for(Quote__c Q:Trigger.New){
       sPIFIDs.add(Q.PIF__c); 
    }

    for(PIF_GDS__c PIF:[Select ID from PIF_GDS__c where ID IN:sPIFIDs ]){
        if(!mPIF.ContainsKey(PIF.ID))
            mPIF.put(PIF.ID,PIF);
    }

    for(Quote__c Q:Trigger.New){
        IF(mPIF.ContainsKey(Q.PIF__c)){
            PIF_GDS__c oPIF = New PIF_GDS__c();
            oPIF=mPIF.get(Q.PIF__c);
            oPIF.Proposal__c=Q.ID;
            lupdatePIF.Add(oPIF);
         }
    }
    if(lupdatePIF.size()>0)
        update lupdatePIF;    
 }
```

Please help me logic for PIF have Revisions numbers(these are unique) 1,2,3,4.....when creating proposal first time based on Revision number 1 propsal needs to get create.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick bit to help get you started. Try thinking in terms of "Related PIFs" and "Related Quotes" and "Related Proposals". So you'll have PIF_GDS__r, Proposal__r and you'll also have Quote__r. You just need to put them into the proper relationships relative to each other as you query. This is a time when Maps very often come in quite handy.